# use of local variable and global variable in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

Hello all I am new to crystal reports. I just want to know what is a `local` and a `global` variable.  Please suggest what is the difference between local and global variables.

Comment: You could try reading Crystal Reports' help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

local variable: as the name says it is local to the formula created... it can't be used outside the formula declared.

**Use: if you want to use the same name for a variable across many formulas then it should be used.**

Global Variable: it can be used out side the scope of the formula created.

**use: during calculations there will be use to reset the variable value to 0 anywhere in the report then this should be used.**

```
Along with this there is one more variable that is `Shared` it also acts as a global variable

use: it is also used in resetting the value and also pass values between main report and sub report and viceversa
```

Edit:***********************************

E.g;

creating formula `count`

```
Global numbervar a;
a:=a+1;
a
```

Now I want to reset the value to 0 on change of every group then I use the below formula in group header as below.

```
Global Numbervar a;
a:=0
```

Comment: Hi Siva can you please explain use of global variable with an example

Comment: **use** in my answer itself is an example... what is your exact requirement

Comment: Hi Siva I Just want to know the difference.Please explain this sentence clearly.**it can be used out side the scope of the formula created**

Comment: it is like if you create a variable `a` with global access then you can't create the same variable `a` in any other formula in a report. Report carries the a reference on whole report for formula see my edit answer.

Answer (score 6):

- `local` - current function or formula field
- `global` - current report (excluding its sub-reports)
- `shared` - current report and its sub-reports